# How to limit expression access to types external in Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, expression, roslyn, side-effects

So I read thru the ways of how to [evaluate expressions](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/01/easy-way-to-create-a-c-lambda-expression-from-a-string-with-roslyn/) with Roslyn and I wonder if it is possible and how to limit expression to a set of basic math operations and operations on a reduced set of types provided by me (no Console.Writeline, singletons, external Dlls etc). How to force and check such expression capabilities reduction for Roslyn expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is evaluate code as expression and analyze the expression, e.g. `Expression<Func<Album, bool>>`.

```
Expression<Func<Album, bool>> discountFilterExpression = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Expression<Func<Album, bool>>>(discountFilter, options);
```

Then use an `ExpressionVisitor` to visit nodes of the expression and check if the expression contains only valid/allowed nodes and types.

For example, the below visitor checks if `Math` is being used within the code evaluated, and set the expression to invalid if so:

```
class NoMathExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public bool IsValid { get; private set; } = true;

    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Math))
        {
            IsValid = false;
        }

        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

In total:

```
// Generate expression
Expression<Func<Album, bool>> discountFilterExpression = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<Expression<Func<Album, bool>>>(discountFilter, options);

// Visit each node using NoMathExpressionVisitor
var expressionVisitor = new NoMathExpressionVisitor();
expressionVisitor.Visit(discountFilterExpression);

// Check result
// For code: a => Math.Abs(a.Quality) > 10, IsValid returns false
if (expressionVisitor.IsValid)
{
    // If the expression is valid, compile the expression to
    // Func<> and run.
    var result = discountFilterExpression.Compile()(album);
}
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/expression-trees-interpreting